# How can a generic base type be cast via reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have the following  class:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    Class<T> type;
    List<T> items;
    public Class<T> getType() { return type; }
    ...
}
```

I need to store objects of the above class in a generic container:

```
public class MyContainer<T> {
    Class<T> type;
    List<MyClass<T>> myClasses;
    public Class<T> getType() { return type; }
    ...
}
```

Let's say later in my code I'm given a generic object as an argument:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        List<MyContainer<?>> containers;
        ...
    }
    public void someMethod(MyClass<?> myClass){
        ...
    }
}
```

I have type T as reflection. I need to cast `MyClass<?>` back to its intended type. So if it was declared as `MyClass<String>` I need to cast it back to `MyClass<String>`. I can't seem to do this with the reflection type because it is only capable of casting T, not `MyClass<T>`.

I could cast T by doing this for example:

```
myClass.getType().cast(myClass.getItem()); // Where getItem returns an object of the type T
```

But what I want is this:

```
myClass.getType().cast(myClass); // getType() returns T not MyClass<T>
```

So the question is, how do I cast a generic base type along with its reflection type, given the scenario above?

Comment: Why do you need this? The generic type `T` doesn't exist at run time (when reflection happens) so I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a list of containers that holds a list of objects which holds a list of objects. In this case: a Container object has a list of MyClass objects, and a MyClass object has a list of T objects. So it is a list within a list within a list of generically typed container. The container must be generic because I need the container to be able to hold any type of object. In the second layer - in MyClass, I need to manage the object differently depending on the type. For example, if it is MyClass<Person> I want to display a table with 10 columns. Or if it's MyClass<Tree> I may only display 5 cols

Comment: I know T doesn't exist at run time, which is why I save it as Class<T> type ... I need to cast the damn object back to its original type - only in this case, I also need the generic base type in the second level of my container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible due to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure). Reflection can't help you here because at runtime the generic type information isn't available. In other words at runtime there is no `MyClass<String>`, there is only `MyClass`. `MyClass<String>` is a pure compile-time creature.

If you have some piece of code that expects a certain type, declare that at *compile time*. This type expectation could be concrete or generic:

```
public void someMethod(MyClass<String> myClass)
```

or

```
public <T> void someMethod(MyClass<T> myClass)
```

If you know the type, you don't need `cast()`, you can just cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
MyClass<String> myClassStr = (MyClass<String>)expression;
```

Comment: thank you, I think I might go with the @SuppressWarnings thing

Comment: The code would compile even without the warning suppression. It's best practice to have a codebase compile without warnings. It's even better to avoid the reason for the warning if possible.
(If the answer solves your problem, please accept it :-))

Answer (score 0):

Since `T` doesn't exist at runtime, which you know, you can't use it. You also can't get a `Class<List<T>>`.

`myClass.getType().cast(myClass.getItem())` doesn't really work for you because if you have a `MyClass<?>` then you also have a `Class<?>` which only returns Object. A `Class<T>` doesn't really help you either, because you need to actually know what `T` is.

You can pretty much do two things.

Use decisions:

```
if(myClass.getType() == String.class) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final MyClass<String> myStrings = (MyClass<String>)myClass;

    // use MyClass<String> ...
}
```

Use polymorphism:

```
MyClass<String> myClass = new MyClass<String>(...,
        new BiConsumer<String, JTable>() { // (or lambda ...)
    @Override
    public void accept(String s, JTable table) {
        // use String ...
        // configure JTable ...
    }
});

... elsewhere ...

public void someMethod(MyClass<?> myClass) {
    someCaptureMethod(myClass);
}

private <T> void someCaptureMethod(MyClass<T> myClass) {
    Consumer<T, JTable> consumer = myClass.getConsumer();

    for(T theT : myClass.getList()) {
        consumer.accept(theT, myTable);
    }
}
```

Generally the second example is considered the "better" way but the code might be longer in versions of Java prior to 8.

Comment: Why is the second considered better? It seems as though the creation and management component is tightly coupled at the beginning of the code. And rather bulky if you have to rewrite the configuration code for each instance of MyClass. Also what if you want to release your code to allow others to simply "create" MyClass objects, and leave the configuration aspect within a "black box"?

Comment: It is the [OOP way to do this type of thing](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism). If you don't like it, you could put the functional object somewhere else, like a Map. Or don't use it. A decision and a cast may be simpler if you have only a few kinds of `T`. The main point to my answer is that these are your two options.

Comment: *"And rather bulky if you have to rewrite the configuration code for each instance of MyClass."* You have to do this anyway. With the coupling thing...going by your question text, I really have no idea what these objects do except that (from your comment) they go in a table so my answer is very general.

Comment: I wasn't criticising your code, but rather just questioning the reason behind what is considered better. To clarify - my intention is to create countless MyClass objects of a few types.

Comment: My second example is also very close to [how JTable works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getDefaultRenderer-java.lang.Class-). It allows the client to specify how their object should be displayed if they want to.